# How to startx with "-logverbose 6" arguments?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, log

How do I pass the `-logverbose 6` arguments to `startx`? It is necessary for submitting a bug report to Nvidia Support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a TTY to login i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Login as yourself

Then type

```
sudo -i
```

to login as root.

I imagine nvidia asked you to run `nvidia-bug-report.sh`

then you can startx

```
startx -- -logverbose 6 :2
```

i.e. this will attempt to start a new X display on TTY 2.

Comment: This is not worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I like fossfreedom's answer but it isn't what I have done in the past. It might work but I'm not sure keeping the old X instance around is a good thing. Here's what I would do:

After Ubuntu loads to a graphical desktop, drop back to a TTY, log in and run:

```
sudo stop gdm   # lightdm instead of gdm on 11.10
sudo startx -logverbose 6
```

It's practically the same, you're just cleaning up the old instance of X before you run the debug instance.

Comment: Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
[    12.916] (EE) No drivers available.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I kept hitting it via Google.  If you're using a newer Ubuntu that uses lightdm, you can edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add this line under `[SeatDefaults]`:

`xserver-command=X -logverbose 6`

(Presumably other display managers have similar facilities to control how they start X, you'd want to check their documentation.)

When you reboot, your normal X log file will now have verbose data.  You can add any other command line arguments you need there, as well.

Source: `zless /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz` via [Is there a list of all the possible configuration options for lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140471/is-there-a-list-of-all-the-possible-configuration-options-for-lightdm)

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04, the file is /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf

Comment: where would I find my normal X log file after such a modification?