# LightDM Customisation KDE or Unity Greeter in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, themes, lightdm, kde-apps

my favorite Distro is Xubuntu, only the GTK greeter let my eyes bleeding (i know, its lightweight and simple). So i check these hints:

[is-there-a-list-of-all-the-possible-configuration-options-for-lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140471/is-there-a-list-of-all-the-possible-configuration-options-for-lightdm)

and:

[how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter)

I set the gtk greeter to the kde greeter and it works very well. But it seems there is no chance to get the customisation user interface from the kubuntu distro. So what are my opinions, to change the style of the kde greeter in xubuntu?